# Table title to match table body (in terms of length)

Tags: tables, lengths

I have a table with 4 columns and my title seems to be far bigger than the main body of the table. This does not look quite good.

Is there anyway to have the length of those two be the same, or at least not to have that big difference?

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

  \begin{table} \caption{My results. The dependent variable is ...}  
  \centering
   \begin{tabular}[htbp!]{@{} cc @{}} 
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{s1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{s2} \\ 
   \hline a & c \\ 
   \hline b & d \\ 
   \hline 
   \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean to auto-adept table-title via table-width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `threeparttable`package for that: it measures the table width and creates a minipage of the width of the table.

I added the `booktabs` and `caption` packages to improve the visual appearance of the table.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = footnotesize, labelfont = sc}
\usepackage{threeparttable, booktabs}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{My results. The dependent variable is ...}
       \begin{tabular}[!h]{ ccc }
       \toprule
       s1 & s2 & s3  \\
        \midrule
        a & c & e \\
        \midrule
        b & d  & f \\
         \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

1- Using the `width` key from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package you can manually adjust the caption width.

2- Using the [`ctable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable) package the width will automatically adapt to the table width (further adjustments to the caption width can be done using `mincapwidth` for too narrow tables).

3- Using the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package and its `\ttabbox` command the width will automatically adapt to the table width.

An example code with the standard settings, the `\ctable` command, and the `width` key passed to `\captionsetup`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table} 
  \caption{The standard behaviour for the caption}  
  \centering
   \begin{tabular}[htbp!]{@{} cc @{}} 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{s1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{s2} \\ 
   \hline text1 & text2 \\ 
   \hline text3 & text4 \\ 
   \hline 
   \end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\ctable[
caption = My results. The dependent variable is ...,
label=tab:test,
]{@{} cc @{}}{}
{
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{s1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{s2} \\ 
   \hline text1 & text2 \\ 
   \hline text3 & text4 \\ 
   \hline 
}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{width=5cm} 
  \caption{My results. The dependent variable is ...}  
  \centering
   \begin{tabular}[htbp!]{@{} cc @{}} 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{s1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{s2} \\ 
   \hline text1 & text2 \\ 
   \hline text3 & text4 \\ 
   \hline 
   \end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An example with the standard settings and `\ttabbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table} 
  \caption{The standard behaviour for the caption}  
  \centering
   \begin{tabular}[htbp!]{@{} cc @{}} 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{s1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{s2} \\ 
   \hline text1 & text2 \\ 
   \hline text3 & text4 \\ 
   \hline 
   \end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \ttabbox{\caption{My results. The dependent variable is ...}}{%
   \begin{tabular}[htbp!]{@{} cc @{}} 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{s1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{s2} \\ 
   \hline text1 & text2 \\ 
   \hline text3 & text4 \\ 
   \hline 
   \end{tabular}%
   } 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another one though. Does the command `ttabbox` work with `longtable`?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis No, it doesn't.

Comment: So it seems that this cannot be fixed with longtables, right?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis Yes, it can. Theres a [threeparttablex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex) package that could be used for `longtable`s.

Comment: I was never able to make both `longtable` and `threeparttable` work together. Any example?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis Search the site or open a new question.